# MongoDb: how to write your mongoDb query result in a file?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

While running a query i want a result of that query into another file
My query is running successfully in mongo terminal.

> ```
> db.questions.find({"question" : {$regex : ".*.*"}},{question :1,_id:0,id:1});
> { "id" : 0, "question" : "Amount was debited from my account, but ticket was not
>  generated. What should I do now?" }
> { "id" : 1, "question" : "How safe is goCash?" }
> { "id" : 2, "question" : "How referral program and goCash works?" }
> ```

Now check following image:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jv7i8.png)

By this i can write in any type of file by just adding >> filename.extension

Now the main problem is with this one:
[image: here]

When i use find instead of findOne and use a regular expression, it shows unexpected token

Anyone knows how i can modify it to get the desired result.

Comment: for better understanding check this link: https://mlichtenberg.wordpress.com/2013/11/21/directing-mongodb-query-results-to-a-file/

Comment: The error is because of invalid syntax. You are using `{"question" : $regex : ".*.*"}` instead of `{"question" : {$regex : ".*.*"}}` (Missing braces).

Comment: D:\mongodb\mongodb\bin>mongo localhost/database -eval "printjson(db.questions.find({"question" : {$regex : ".*.*"}}))"  // I used this as you suggested but still problem sustain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `"`(qoutes)  inside the command line. Try using `{'question' : { \$regex : '.*'}}`.

Further the db.collection.find() method returns a cursor. Redirecting it to a file will just write the cursor json.To access the documents, you need to iterate the cursor.

```
mongo localhost/database -eval "var cursor = {'question' : { \$regex : '.*'}}; while(cursor.hasNext()){ printjson( cursor.next())}"
```

All the examples in the [blog](https://mlichtenberg.wordpress.com/2013/11/21/directing-mongodb-query-results-to-a-file/) return result as json format.

You can also use any of the [mongo-drivers](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/) to write your result to a file.

Comment: single quotes worked for me . Thanks But forward slash will not be needed. And if some else also following this answer, you would need to prefix your query.Final statement will look like this.'mongo localhost/database --eval "var x = db.questions.find({'question':{$regex : '.*.*'}},{question :1,id:1,_id:0}); while(x.hasNext()) { printjson( x.next() ) }" >> out.txt'